Does $f \in L^1 \implies f \log f \in L^1$?

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $R^3$. Suppose $f \in L^1(\Omega)$ with $f>0$ a.e. Prove or disprove: $f \log f \in L^1(\Omega)$.

Attempt: I am stuck at this for a while and unable to make any progress. This is the only inequality that I could find but it does not help to conclude anything:
$$f-1\leq f \log f \leq f^2-f$$
I would really apprecaite any insights/hints.

This is false. There is even a space called LlogL which is used in Fourier Analysis and is different from L^1.

Pick a collection of sets $\Omega_n$ in $\Omega$ which are pairwise disjoint and such that $\Omega_n$ has measure equal to $c2^{-n}$, where $c>0$ is a fixed constant independent of $n$. On $\Omega_n$ let $f$ be equal to $2^n/n^2$ and extend by zero to the rest of $\Omega$. Then $$\Vert f\Vert_1 =\sum_{n=1}^\infty c 2^{-n} \frac{2^n}{n^2}$$ which converges. On the other hand $$\Vert f\log(f)\Vert_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} c\frac{2^n}{n^2} \log\left( c\frac{2^n}{n^2}\right)$$ which diverges.

Consider $$ f(x)=\frac1{x\log(x)^2}\quad\text{on }(0,1/2) $$

related. See also the classic paper E.M. Stein, Note on the class log, Studia Math. 32 (1969)).

Please do not delete questions on which others have provided help. Furthermore, this question may prove useful to other users.
